# Vuetify tree data-table

Tags: vuetify.js

how can I embed a v-tree-view component in v-data-table ?

I have tried so many times but without any result .

with no vuetify v-tree-table forexample , here comes the question , how to integrate the v-tree-view with v-data-table ?

Comment: Can you please add some code to show your previous attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a slot to customize any column. So there you can insert your treeview. An example:

```html
<template>
    <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="cosas"
    >
    <template v-slot:[`item.description`]>
        <td>
            <template>
                <v-treeview :items="treeItems"></v-treeview>
            </template>
        </td>
    </template>

    </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',

   data () {
        return {
            headers:[
                { text: 'Name', value: 'name'},
                { text: 'Description', value: 'description'},
            ],
            cosas:[
                { name: 'Item1', description: 'description1'},
                { name: 'Item2', description: 'description2'},
            ],
            treeItems: [
                {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Applications :',
                children: [
                    { id: 2, name: 'Calendar : app' },
                    { id: 3, name: 'Chrome : app' },
                    { id: 4, name: 'Webstorm : app' },
                ],
                },
                {
                id: 5,
                name: 'Documents :',
                children: [
                    {
                    id: 6,
                    name: 'vuetify :',
                    children: [
                        {
                        id: 7,
                        name: 'src :',
                        children: [
                            { id: 8, name: 'index : ts' },
                            { id: 9, name: 'bootstrap : ts' },
                        ],
                        },
                    ],
                    },
                    {
                    id: 10,
                    name: 'material2 :',
                    children: [
                        {
                        id: 11,
                        name: 'src :',
                        children: [
                            { id: 12, name: 'v-btn : ts' },
                            { id: 13, name: 'v-card : ts' },
                            { id: 14, name: 'v-window : ts' },
                        ],
                        },
                    ],
                    },
                ],
                },
                {
                id: 15,
                name: 'Downloads :',
                children: [
                    { id: 16, name: 'October : pdf' },
                    { id: 17, name: 'November : pdf' },
                    { id: 18, name: 'Tutorial : html' },
                ],
                },
                {
                id: 19,
                name: 'Videos :',
                children: [
                    {
                    id: 20,
                    name: 'Tutorials :',
                    children: [
                        { id: 21, name: 'Basic layouts : mp4' },
                        { id: 22, name: 'Advanced techniques : mp4' },
                        { id: 23, name: 'All about app : dir' },
                    ],
                    },
                    { id: 24, name: 'Intro : mov' },
                    { id: 25, name: 'Conference introduction : avi' },
                ],
                },
            ],
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Set your filters in the template to insert it only in those cells that you need it.

Answer (score 0):

i try with many libraries but i feel very hard dificult, because i want to use crud in nodes child, i created solucion: i used a table   of type expanded and this expended area insert other table  for child. you can read in official page about expand table:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#expandable-rows

my code:

```
 <v-data-table
             item-key="_id"
            :headers="headers"
            :items="items"
            :single-expand="singleExpand"
            :expanded.sync="expanded"
            show-expand
            height="670"
            fixed-header
            sort-by="_id"
            class="elevation-1 mt-sm-5 mt-md-5 mt-lg-5 mt-xl-5"
            >

           <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
      <td :colspan="headers.length" style="background-color:#C0D0D0">


        <v-card class="mx-auto my-1" max-width="900" outlined>
         
          <v-card-text>
            <div>
         
            <span><strong> Delivery {{item.name_driver}}</strong></span>
            </div>
            <v-divider></v-divider>
              <div>
              
                <v-data-table
                :headers="headersChild"
                :items="item.children"
                :items-per-page="5"
                class="elevation-1"
            >
            </v-data-table>
                        
              </div>
          </v-card-text>
          
        </v-card>


        
        
        
        </td>
    </template>
    
    
    </v-data-table>
```